# MongoDB model generate for FASTAPI python similar to sqlacodegen

Tags: mongodb, model, fastapi

Is there a tool that reads the structure of an existing MONGO DB database and generates the appropriate model.py code, using the declarative style if possible.
for FASTAPI python motor?

Comment: Are you looking to convert a mongodb schema to a relational database schema?

Comment: No, for fastapi project to create models.py from existing mongoDB schema

I figured out "datamodel-code-generator" this helps 


https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/

Answer (score 0):

https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/

This code generator creates pydantic model from an mongoDB json file

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.